# Not sure if my Arduino Uno is damaged

Tags: arduino-uno

When I plug the USB cable to my Arduino and try to upload a sketch I get thtis error:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/cu.usbmodem1411": No such file or directory
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

when I go to Tools > ports I can't find the USB port.
The Arduino still working and green ligh is on, so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Does the Uno show up under ` -> "About this Mac" -> "More info" -> "System Report"->"Hardware"->"USB"`?

Comment: You should really search on `Arduino Inappropriate ioctl` possibly with `mac` that would give you some results worth reading.
http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13299/inappropriate-ioctl-for-device or https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=292284.0 and  http://askubuntu.com/questions/646254/arduino-serial-port-com1-problem are all people with the same error message. Try what worked for them.

Comment: Probably never mind, since the Arduino isn't even recognized by the PC, try to fix that first. If you try another Arduino, you would be able to tell if the problem is on the PC or on the Arduino.

Comment: Actually, you might still want to check out those links. Try running your IDE as administrator (or what it is at mac).

Answer (score 2):

Have heard of similar problems with Mac. Not a Mac user myself. Sometimes the Arduino can somehow trigger a current fault in the USB of Mac's and will need to be shut down and rebooted for it to work again.

Try rebooting your Mac.

If you have a cheap chinese Arduino you might need other drivers for it. Check what chip you have closest to the usb connector.

Comment: I have tried with 2 Mac laptops, same thing happened. an electronics guy told me that the IC is burnt, is this right?

Comment: I would check that you have the correct driver before i would make that assumtion.

Comment: @AfnanHumdan and I would check it again, because the "the IC is burnt" is the common way to say "I don't have the time to look at it, so just change it". Moreover you didn't say if the board ever worked. Then try using another pc (not a mac) just to double check. If it doesn't work, maybe flashing again the firmware on the atmega16u2 (the usb-serial interface IC) can solve the problem..

Comment: The Arduino only requests 100mA from the USB port. If you draw more than that it may decide to cut you off. 100mA is somewhat conservative (they could have set it to ask for 500mA) but it does allow it to work on an unpowered hub without the hub shutting it off - as long as you stay within that 100mA budget. Many systems ignore that limit though and provide many amps of power, but the Mac may be more sensitive.

Comment: @Majenko the Arduino request 100mah and could ask for 500 mah. I beg you to explain this. The usb 2.0 standard says a port should be able to deliver 500mah, whether the arduino draws that from the port or not is irrelevant unless exceeding 500mah where the controller might disconnect your device.

Comment: You are thinking purely electrical. USB also contains a protocol. That protocol as a portion in it whereby the device tells the host "I will require this much power". If that request exceeds what the port can provide it should be disconnected (unpowered hubs can only provide 100mA per port). If the device draws more than it has told the host it will be using then the host is at liberty to disconnect the device to protect itself.

Comment: I just read up on this, and you are correct according to the  standard. I however are using hubs, always and have no problems drawing up to close 3 A before being cut off from those, with only power pins connected.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing this type of issue. But it has resolved itself now. I go to `Tool` >> Select `Port` after Select `USB modem` its work fine.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34066)

Comment: I can't agree this isn't an answer. It clearly spells out what to do to resolve the issue. If that doesn't solve the problem that is another issue. To whoever has been flagging this, answers are not to be flagged merely because they are wrong.

Comment: @NickGammon, the question is a Mac specific problem, where no ports are listed in IDE. how does this 'late' and 'me-to' answer answer the question? ('my' previous comment was generated by SE)

Comment: @Juraj On the Mac you get Tools -> Ports, as mentioned in the question. Bad answers don't have to be flagged for moderator attention. Just leave a comment stating why it won't work in your opinion and optionally vote it down.

Comment: @NickGammon, SE system asked me if this is a low quality late answer that should be deleted. I didn't flag it directly

Comment: Yes, but you *agreed*, right? You can skip answers that don't seem low quality. It's just an algorithm.

Comment: @NickGammon, yes I agreed.  the SE system added the answer to review because it is late and short and I reviewed it and I think, the answer doesn't answer the question. because if the list is empty you can select nothing. but you are the admin and you can delete the flag and let it be. there was an other late answer in the review list and it was ok. and then some answers I skipped because I was not sure